# Exponential family distribution where variance is greater than mean in python

Tags: python, glm, poisson

Can someone please suggest how to fit a distribution from exponential family with variance greater than mean to build GLM model in python.

In R, quasipoisson seemed to work well.
But I couldn't find a similar distribution in python.

```
glm_fit1 <- glm(data = msdata, 
    family = quasipoisson(link = "log")...
```

This was the code used in R.
But I want to build the model in python.

Comment: Unfortunately, the most common implementation of GLMs in python ([statsmodels'](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html)) does not not account for quasi-likelihood methods. You may try alternatives such as stated by this [github comment](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4942#issuecomment-414128677), but discussing those is out of scope of SO.

Comment: you can use a negative binomial if your variance is larger than your mean. this should be close enough to the poisson. what is the end goal?